# Scheduling using Camel - Quartz2 and Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to setup a scheduler using Camel and Quartz2 and my goal is to read messages from queue only in a specific time period.I am getting the following error on start of the server.

> org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelSpringBootInitializationException:
>   org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route
>   route1:
>   Route(route1)[[From[quartz2://simpleTimer?cron=0/1+0+13-15+?...
>   because of Failed to resolve endpoint:
>   quartz2://simpleTimer?cron=0%2F1+0+13-15+%3F+*+MON-FRI due to: No
>   component found with scheme: quartz2

This is the pom entry

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-quartz2</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

code snippet in routes

```
 from("quartz2://simpleTimer?cron=0/1+0+13-14+?+*+MON-FRI")
        .log("Reading msgs")
        .from("some queue")
        .bean("myBean")
```

Also tried with this

```
from("quartz2://testGroup/someName?cron=0/1+0+13-14+?+*+MON-FRI").
```

I made multiple attempts in fixing the issue but failed, can anyone help me in fixing this?
Can I use simpleTimer along with Cron settings or Is there any other approach? 
any suggestions/help in this regards would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates you have not added the dependency in maven to camel-quartz2 component.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-quartz2</artifactId>
    <version>x.x.x</version>
    <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you put 2 from in the same route. Each route has **only one from**.

When you read from a queue, for example with jms component, you get directly the messages as soon as they arrive. So quarz component is not needed.

Which component are you using for reading from a queue? Probably this component has more options that they can help you!

Answer (score 0):

This got resolved when I created a Bean instance of QuartzComponent in routes file.Also, we can have multiple "from" in the routes definition.